# php inventory management open source

Tags: php

iam looking for a php/mysql open source inventory management software.
Can anyone suggest me a good, free script?

I have heard about VTigerCRM, SugarCRM, Magento... which among these is the best for inventory, and anything else is preferable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out, http://phpbms.org/ I dont know to what extent it will satisfy your needs, but it can be easily customized. And it is open source running on php/mysql.

Comment: Hi, it is looking like a LAMP stack... i need for Windows..

Comment: Iam just looking for a basic inventory system, that has features like: tracking requirement, production, stock details and customers. Please suggest me a good one.

Comment: For now, i got a sample stock management script online, and using it. :)

Comment: You can run this on windows without issues, just need to install php and mysql on windows. I dont know of any others at the moment, if I stumble upon anything I will post it here.

Comment: Thanks serialk for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can very well use it on WAMP stack, if I am not wrong.